# How to Display product category ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) on WooCommerce PDF packing slips?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to show estimated delivery times on the Packing slips. (WP overnight WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips).

I'm using a snippet that displays either the category field or, if its there, the product category field. It works fine elsewhere on my site.

I'm fiddling around with this snippet: https://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/displaying-product-custom-fields/

This is what I've got so far.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta', 'wpo_wcpdf_product_custom_field', 10, 3 );

function wpo_wcpdf_product_custom_field( $template_type, $item, $order ) {
  if ( $template_type == 'packing-slip' ) {
    // check if product exists first
    if ( empty( $item[ 'product' ] ) ) return;
    // Check en display delivery time

    if ( $plevertijd = get_field( 'plevertijd', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
      echo '
       <p style="font-size: small; margin-top: 10px;">Verwachte levertijd: ' . $plevertijd . ' (vanaf besteldatum)</p>
       ';
    } else {
      $terms = get_the_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' );

      if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
        $term = array_pop( $terms );

        if ( $levertijd = get_field( 'levertijd', $term ) ) {
          echo '
            <p style="font-size: small; margin-top: 10px;">Verwachte levertijd: ' . $levertijd . ' (vanaf besteldatum)</p>
            ';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

But that gives me an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_product_id() on array

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Sure its not `$item['product']->get_product_id()`?  The error is saying that `$item` is an array...

Comment: If i use that I get the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Variation::get_product_id(). Maybe I'm placing that wrong. What part are you replacing?